# echo trims multiple white spaces in the middle of string

Tags: php, html, string, whitespace, echo

The following code outputs a b:

```
$var="a   b"; // I inserted 3 white spaces, and HTML is rendering only one
echo $var;
```

The issue is that if I store **$var** in a table, it will KEEP the white spaces, and while reading, it strips them back. The striped data gets as it is updated in another table, resulting in mismatch of same values in both the tables.

I tried google search and found in a thread that its how HTML behaves. Any hope on how can I fix this?

Comment: with css: `white-space: pre;`

Answer (score 7):

The normal white-space behavior is to collapse everything to one space. You can modify it by changing the `white-space:` css rule to `white-space: pre;` or `white-space: pre-wrap;`

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/white-space for more details

Answer (score 3):

Multiple spaces are trimmed in the html output of most browsers, not in the html code itself. If you want multiple spaces to render you can use `str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;",$var)` which will tell the browsers to render each whitespace character. The same goes for multiple linebreaks, using `nl2br()`

Answer (score 0):

HTML always strips extra whitespace characters (for displaying). If you want to prevent this use `&nbsp;`. However it sounds like you are using it for alignment. Never do that!

What if the text changes?

Comment: Not using for alignment though, but will try str_replace with &nbsp. Thank you for answering